# Custom attributes in composer.json

Tags: php, attributes, composer-php

Is possible to add/create custom attributes on composer.json?

Like this:

```
(...)
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4"
    },
    'custom': {
        "username": "RahPT",
        "foo": "bar"
    },
(...)
```

Comment: Can you? Yes. The simplest way is probably the [`extra`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra) section, although I don’t know how that composes. The more formal way is through a [composer plugin](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md), however. That said, it is a rare case to have to do that. Make sure it isn’t config stuff that should be stored elsewhere

Comment: For what purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible to add/create custom attributes on composer.json?

(Possible,) Yes, it is a file containing JSON Text (unmarshalled by Composer with `json_decode()`).

If you consider to publish your package thought, consult `composer validate` if your own modification to the JSON Text is eligible for publication.

Also consider forward compatibility: How do you know that at a some time in the future the `custom` (or any other) keyword gets a meaning in Composer and then your data clashes?

Better use the `extra` keyword as it is already defined, can contain any data and is per package.

But only put things into `composer.json` that are related to the package, like the name or other metadata of your project, and keep project configuration files with your project (not in composer.json). Create your own `project.json` file for example.

Comment: The "extra" property is the answer.  
@haker Thankyou!

Comment: Yes, kudos also to Chris Haas who commented on it earlier under your question. Also consider to formulate your own rationale why you add it for now as in the future it might turn out cumbersome and then its good to not start over from the very low grounds. Compare with the question of purpose by Sammitch.